# Recurrence Relation for Recursive Algorithm

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, pseudocode, recurrence

I've been given an algorithm in pseudo-code that I'm supposed to find a recurrence relation for, as well as solve that relation to analyse it's complexity.

The Algorithm:

```
Find(A[p..r])
{
  if(p == r)
    return A[p];

  else
  {
    temp1 = Find(A[p..((p + r)/2)]);
    temp2 = Find(A[(((p + r)/2) + 1)..r]);

    if(temp1 <= temp2)
      return temp1;
    else
      return temp2;
  }
}
```

Considering that the basic operation for this code should be the two comparisons if(p == r) and if(temp1 <= temp2), the recurrence I came up with was [T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2c], with c being the amount of time taken to do one comparison.

Here are the steps I took:

```
1: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2c

2: T(n/2) = 2(2T(n/2^2) + 2c) + 2c
          = 2^2T(n/2^2) + 2^2c + 2c

3: T(n/4) = 2(2^2T(n/2^3) + 2c) + 2c
          = 2^3*T(n/2^3) + 2^3c + 2^2c + 2c
```

At this point, I notice that I can simplify the summation of constant c using the geometric formula a(1 - r^i)/(1 - r), thus coming up with the following:

```
Relation = 2^i*T(n/2^i) - c(1 - 2^i)
```

Since T(1) = c, because then we're only doing one comparison, n = 2^i, lg n = i,

I resolve the relation to the following:

```
2^i*T(n/n) - c(1 - 2^i)
= (2^lg n * c) - c(1 - 2^lg n)
= (2^lg n * c) - c + (c * 2^lg n)
= 2cn - c
```

In which case, T(n) = O(n).

I was wondering if somebody would mind looking over my work to see if I'd missed anything out over my working? Thanks a lot for the help, guys!

P.S: Just to confirm my suspicions, all this algorithm does is to look for the smallest value stored within the array, right?

P.P.S: In case anyone was wondering, in this case, the base of ln would be 2.